# Using dev.new() with postscript()

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot, postscript

How can I fix the following code?

```
postscript("test.eps")
    dev.new(width=5,height=2)
    plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Obviously I want to export this small height plot to an `eps` file. Right now a completely blank `.eps` will be exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the extraneous call to `plot.new()` and it should work fine:

```
postscript("test.eps", width = 5, height = 2)
    plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```